# How to save filename with space on Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to save file in document directory using

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc 1.pdf",];
NSString *pdfLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

I am opening this file using a web view

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfLocation];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[urlRequest release];
```

This fails if the the file name has a space.How should I save file so that space in the filename is maintained.

Comment: Try this : @"abc\ 1.pdf"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIWebView` expects a file URL in this case. Change the line to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfLocation];
```